# Is it possible to assign a resolved promise to a property of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, promise

I'm playing around with promises here and trying to assign a pair of resolved promises as properties of an object by wrapping each promise in an IIFE.  However, the resolved promises are never assigned, although they are definitely pulling down the requested data.

It would be great if I could get this to work since it's more terse and expressive than success/then/error/catch blocks.  Is it possible to use promises this way?

```
var obj = function() {   
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      return {
          primary: function() {
              return this.promisifiedHttpRequest(primaryQuery, options);
          }.call(this),
          secondary: function() {
              return this.promisifiedHttpRequest(secondaryQuery, options);
          }.call(this)
      }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

The expected result is as follows:

```
var obj = {
    primary: primaryQueryResponse,
    secondary: secondaryQueryResponse
};
```

Comment: What are you seeking to accomplish by returning an object from the function you pass to a promise constructor (the return value will just be ignored), and calling a promise constructor without ever using the `resolve` or `reject` parameter (the produced promise will never resolve). Can you please explain in detail what you think this code is doing? All it's doing for me is making my brain hurt. It doesn't strike me as very expressive.

Comment: I'm kinda with JLRishe, and yet you do claim that it's pulling down the requested data. So, I'd be interested in seeing what the stack trace is for that point, if you were to put a breakpoint inside those innermost functions in your example.

Comment: @Katana314 Those two calls to `promisifiedHttpRequest()` are definitely happening. It's simply that the promises they produce are being placed on an object that is then thrown into the abyss, never to be seen again. The stack trace is simple: [that outer function] -> [the IIFE] -> [Promise constructor] -> [anonymous function] -> [inner IIFE] -> [promisifiedHttpRequest]

Comment: Ah! Yes, it took me too long to notice the `.call(this)` parts. Something tells me what he's looking for is something like Promise.all (can't remember if that's part of the native Promise API)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm new to promises and trying to work it out in my mind, so bear with me.  I added some context to my question to clarify the desired result.  I am aware of the .all method, but was wondering if it was possible to do without it.

Comment: Not really a way around `all()` (or similar helpers). However notice that your result will never be the object itself, it will be a *promise for the object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JLRishe said, it's a little hard to interpret exact intentions with that code. I think this is what you're looking for. This will give back a promise with an array-result.

```
return Promise.all([this.promisifiedHttpRequest(primaryQuery, options),
this.promisifiedHttpRequest(secondaryQuery, options)]);
```

Or, if you liked having a "{primary: ..., secondary: ...}" object, try this:

```
    return Promise.all([this.promisifiedHttpRequest(primaryQuery, options),
this.promisifiedHttpRequest(secondaryQuery, options)]).then(function(resultArr) {
  return {
    primary: resultArr[0],
    secondary: resultArr[1]
  }
});
```

It took me a while to learn this, and perhaps it's not something to abuse, but the return value of `.then()` is very useful for "converting" a promise to something else.